# how can plot multi line plot with legends as other column name

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtgLQ.jpg)[first image is plot which i want but with legend as the sentiment column values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmZj5.png)

[data]

is there is any subsituet to plot line graph like this where every line is of color representing each value of column unique sentiment like red is for negative blue is for positive ....
i have tried to plot like this but it is not explainable to any one.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if this is what you searching for

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)
y = x**2
dydx = np.cos(x)

cmap = plt.get_cmap("hsv",1000)

colors = cmap(np.linspace(0,1,200)) #200 - a tuple for each data point

plt.scatter(x,y,c=colors)
```

could you perhaps put the question a little more precisely?
https://petercbsmith.github.io/color-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 columns, one is total value, one is name of brand and one is total count.

I wanted to plot a line graph with x as the total count, y axis as total value corresponded to the name of brands multi line plit type